# Stucked on Loops, not sure what is the wrong

Tags: java, android

I'm a just a beginner to android & java. I'm trying to build an app that will tell you if you win or lose base on the Martingale on gambling.

My concept is, you can set your money, target and the minimum bet.

for example is if I set my current money is 1000, and my target is to get 1100, and the minimum bet is 100, the app will auto run the function for example 10 times and calculate the win rate.

now I'm stucked, the android studio shows no error, however, whenever i try to emulate the app, it show "unfortunately, app has stopped" everything seem just fine to me, i don't know how to find the error... please guide me. million thanks

```
package com.example.android.gambling;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.text.Editable;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        }

        EditText cMoney = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.money);
        double currentMoney = Double.parseDouble(cMoney.getText().toString());

        EditText target = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.target);
        double theTarget = Double.parseDouble(target.getText().toString());

        EditText bet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bet);
        double minBet = Double.parseDouble(bet.getText().toString());

        boolean findRate = calRate(currentMoney, theTarget, minBet);


        public void seeRate(View view) {


            TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            textview.setText("You " + winPercentage());



        }

        public boolean calRate(double currentMoney, double theTarget, double minBet) {

            while (currentMoney>minBet){
                boolean win = winRate();
                if (win){
                    currentMoney += minBet;
                    minBet = minBet;
                }
                else {
                    currentMoney -= minBet;
                    minBet *= 2;
                }
                if (currentMoney>=theTarget){
                    return true;
                }

            }

            return false;
        }

        private boolean winRate() {
            double d = Math.random();
            if (d < 0.5)
            return true;
            else
                return false;

        }

        public int winPercentage (){
            int numberWin = 0;
            for (int i=0; i<=10; i++){
                boolean win = calRate(currentMoney, theTarget, minBet);
                if (win){
                    numberWin = numberWin + 1;
                }

            }
            return numberWin/10*100;
        }
    }
```

Edit(1)

```
 package com.example.android.gambling;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    EditText cMoney = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.money);
    double currentMoney = Double.parseDouble(cMoney.getText().toString());

    EditText target = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.target);
    double theTarget = Double.parseDouble(target.getText().toString());

    EditText bet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bet);
    double minBet = Double.parseDouble(bet.getText().toString());

    boolean findRate = calRate(currentMoney, theTarget, minBet);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }


    public void seeRate(View view) {


        TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textview.setText("You " + winPercentage());



    }

    public boolean calRate(double currentMoney, double theTarget, double minBet) {

        while (currentMoney>minBet){
            boolean win = winRate();
            if (win){
                currentMoney += minBet;
                minBet = minBet;
            }
            else {
                currentMoney -= minBet;
                minBet *= 2;
            }
            if (currentMoney>=theTarget){
                return true;
            }

        }

        return false;
    }

    private boolean winRate() {
        double d = Math.random();
        if (d < 0.5)
        return true;
        else
            return false;

    }

    public int winPercentage (){
        int numberWin = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<=10; i++){
            boolean win = calRate(currentMoney, theTarget, minBet);
            if (win){
                numberWin = numberWin + 1;
            }

        }
        return numberWin/10*100;
    }
}
```

Comment: I rolled back a lot of your edits. Stackoverflow isn't a forum where you can manipulate your question to ask new stuff. Then you have a new question, then create a new post and leave your older question alone.

Comment: look at your logcat. read the exception stacktrace. do some basic debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```java
private EditText cMoney;
private double currentMoney;
private EditText target;
private double theTarget;
private EditText bet;
private double minBet;
private boolean findRate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  cMoney = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.money);
  currentMoney = Double.parseDouble(cMoney.getText().toString());
  target = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.target);
  theTarget = Double.parseDouble(target.getText().toString());
  bet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bet);
  minBet = Double.parseDouble(bet.getText().toString());
  findRate = calRate(currentMoney, theTarget, minBet);
}
```

You can't put the code like this outside of any method/constructor, unless it's static/initializer block and there's definitely no reason to use them here.

Also, I see that your parameter name in `calRate` is `currentMoney` same as your variable, try to avoid this, it may be confusing for someone else reading your code, for you and maybe even for compiler if you go too far.

Comment: Hi, Thanks you very much for your comment, as per you advice, i have added those under onCreate, however, now pop out new error saying that in winPercentage, it couldn't resolve the "currentMoney" and so on...

Comment: No, you didn't do as I said, your variables need to be declared above the `onCreate` method and you're doing this in `onCreate` method, look carefully at my post. Your variables need to be instance variables, and now they are local variables in your `onCreate` method, so they are not visible anywhere else :)

Comment: HI, now that i've put it above onCreate, and it back to old issue, which is whenever i start the app through emulator, it show "unfortunately, app has stopped", is that anythings wrong with the code? sorry that i'm really new at android, sometime may not get what you mean...

Comment: Look carefully again at my post. In `onCreate` method you do `EditText cMoney = ...` etc., and look at my post. `cMoney` is already declared, now you need to assign value to it, and what you're doing is declaring it again.

Comment: Hi, I'm kind of lost again... would you mind if you show me the exact code, so that i can compare with mine to figure it out where exactly i went wrong...?

Comment: Hi, really thanks you very much for your patient on teaching the newbie like me... i just copy & paste the code given, and still the same error, showing that "unfortunately, app has stopped."

Comment: Ok, what is error in your logcat? There should be whole stack trace with some error in the console.

Comment: Hi, i added a image up there. Million Thanks :)

Comment: Oh, well, right now you are trying to get the values from 3 fields and they are empty. You need to do that after let's say you clicked a button. So user types input into the 3 edit texts, then he clicks a button and then the result is shown to him. You need to add a button in your layout and set `onClick` method or listener for it, and there it needs to do the math and show result.

Comment: Hi, i did add a onlick button for that. this is the onclick button i added...

    public void seeRate(View view) {


        TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textview.setText("You " + winPercentage());

Comment: Hi Whatzs, thanks you very much for keep helping me, and i appreciate that very much... i think that's it, i should stop wasting your time, i should get back to re-learn the fundamental before i  start writing a code, thanks you very much for your guide :)

Answer (score 0):

Put this:

```
    EditText cMoney = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.money);
    double currentMoney = Double.parseDouble(cMoney.getText().toString());

    EditText target = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.target);
    double theTarget = Double.parseDouble(target.getText().toString());

    EditText bet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bet);
    double minBet = Double.parseDouble(bet.getText().toString());

    boolean findRate = calRate(currentMoney, theTarget, minBet);
```

Inside brackets of method onCreate() and then export variables theTarget, minBet, findRate and currentMoney into fields so that they can be visible in other parts of this class.

Comment: Hi, Thanks you very much for your comment, as per you advice, i have added those under onCreate, however, now pop out new error saying that in winPercentage, it couldn't resolve the "currentMoney" and so on...